# question of proof from Analysis I byTerence Tao

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, set-theory

In Analysis I the proof of Distributive law is following:
**Proposition 2.3.4 (Distributive law)**.
For any natural numbers $a$,$b$,$c$,
we have: $$a(b + c) = ab + ac$$ and $$(b + c)a = ba + ca.$$

**Proof.**

Since multiplication is commutative we only need to show the first
identity $a(b + c) = ab + ac.$
 We keep $a$ and $b$ fixed, and use induction on $c$.

Let’s prove the base case $c = 0$, i.e., $a(b + 0) = ab + a0$. The left-hand side is $ab$, while the right-hand side is $ab + 0 = ab$, so we are done with the base case. Now let us suppose inductively that $a(b+c) =ab + ac$, and let us prove that $a(b + (c++)) = ab + a(c++)$.

The left-hand side is $a((b + c)++) = a(b + c) + a$, while the right-hand side is 
$ab + ac + a = a(b + c) + a$ by the induction hypothesis, and so we can close the induction.
So my question is that when we perform Mathematical induction only for $c$, can we show that the law of multiplication and distribution holds for any natural number $abc$？ as it says in the book "For any natural numbers $a$,$b$,$c$"

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary natural numbers when inducting on $c$. Thus, the induction completes the proof for an arbitrary $a,b,c$.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head.What I don't understand is the meaing "a and b fixed"Does this mean that the two variables a,b are assigned a natural number and then remain unchanged when using mathematical induction on the variable c, or is there another explanation?

Comment: Yeah, Tao probably says "fix a,b" to emphasize that we are not inducting on those variables. Note that we are not fixing a particular a,b for the entire duration of the induction. We first fix a,b and do the base case. This shows that ANY a,b works with c=0. Then we fix a,b and do the inductive step. This shows that ANY a,b works for the inductive step. Note that the inductive step wouldn't work unless we proved the base case for arbitrary a,b.